# qemu-kvm Q35 Windows XP drivers

Tags: windows-xp, linux-kvm

Windows XP does not have drivers for AHCI and SMBus controller for emulated Q35 (qemu-kvm). Does a driver for emulated Q35 exist? I have found only Intel driver but the license allows use of it only with Intel hardware.

I want to passthrough a USB controller to Windows XP guest. The controller uses PCI-Express. Is it right to passthrough this USB controller as PCI device in pc-i440fx-2.8 emulated machine? It works for me, but I am not sure that such use is right. The arguments of qemu-system-i386 command: "-device vfio-pci,host=00:12.0,id=usb1 -device vfio-pci,host=00:12.2,id=usb2".

The USB device I want to use is Angioscan and it does not work when I passthrough it as USB device (or the USB host). As far as I know the device does not have Linux support. It seems to work in Windows XP guest with passthroughed USB controller as PCI device.